# Xamarin.Auth - Facebook OAuth not showing mobile friendly views

Tags: ios, facebook, xamarin, oauth-2.0, xamarin.auth

I'm currently implementing OAuth authentication with Xamarin.Auth in one of our applications. We're implementing Facebook and Google sign in.
For some reason the desktop Facebook login screen is shown instead of the responsive mobile view.

I'm using the Xamarin.Auth example code:

```
var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator (
    clientId: "App ID from https://developers.facebook.com/apps",
    scope: "",
    authorizeUrl: new Uri ("https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/"),
    redirectUrl: new Uri ("http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html"));
```

The use of https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/ indicates that the mobile view should be used, but it doesn't.

Has anyone had the same issue before or has an idea why this may happen?

P.S.: I've already tried to download the sample application from the Xamarin.Auth GitHub page. When I enter our Facebook App ID in the sample application, the mobile screen does show up! This would indicate that the Facebook App is correctly set up.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that we set an odd User Agent. That's why Facebook decided to show the desktop view instead of the mobile friendly view.